# Are session persistence and health checks exclusive in NGINX?

Tags: nginx, data-persistence

[Session Persistence](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/http-load-balancer/#enabling-session-persistence) in NGINX Plus provides multiple ways to have a client consistently use the same server to ensure continuity. And the [Health Checks](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/http-health-check/) provide the ability to route around servers where are down or not communicating through the load balancing mechanism. It sounds like, in the documentation, the two would not work together, that you can have both data persistence and load balancing routing around downed servers, but that, if the server you are connected to goes down, either data persistence will route you to a different server, or it will keep you to the same (nonfunctional) server. Is there a way to maintain session persistence when the load balancing / health check routes you away from the server you were using?

I have searched through the NGINX documentation, and watched some of their videos, but I haven't found anything promising.